# People gathering in a cavern to launch a spacecraft(?)

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was a kid, so probably in the late-80s or 90s, I caught bits of a movie on TV where it seemed like a group of people were gathering and holding hands in a circle in a cavern in order to try to do something having to do with a spacecraft.  I remember that the cavern scenes were very warmly lit (lots of oranges and browns, as though the light were coming from a fire).  I also got the impression that the cavern was below a somewhat-rustic/rural structure like a farmhouse, though maybe those were different scenes.  The people all seemed to be wearing a pendant or amulet of some kind (maybe with a leaf symbol on it?).  I believe there was also an aspect of intense time pressure; if they weren't able to complete their effort soon, they would fail badly (maybe the feds/MiB would show up, maybe their launch window would close, maybe both).

Edit: It was live action, not cartoon.

I am unclear on many points:

1. What exactly they were trying to do (I'm *pretty sure* they were trying to launch or guide a spacecraft, but then again it had a strong "magical ritual" feeling to it; maybe it was some kind of psionic effort?)
2. Whether the people were themselves trying to escape, or whether they were acting to help someone else (an alien?) to escape
3. Whether they were the "good guys" or the "bad guys"

Feels pretty sketchy when I write it out like that, but hopefully it's enough for someone to recognize--I remember it from time to time and would love to find out what was actually going on!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This reminds me of [Night of the Red Hunter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0224930/), a 1989 New Zealand TV sci-fi series. Can be found on YouTube as single movie

At around 1:15:50 there is a scene like the one described in the question:

[image]

and the amulets/pendants are shown here:

[image]

Comment: Given that the link has been up on YouTube for nine years, I don't think we've got much to worry about copyright strikes...

Comment: Yes!  You found it!!!  I haven't had time to watch it fully yet, but I jumped through it a little to check and the scenes at e.g. 1:03:00 match the "warm lighting" that I remembered--and that scene is juxtaposed with people in the "farmhouse-like" structure--and at 1:11:25 you can see the leaf-like thing that I recalled (the pendants were apparently a different thing, as in your second screenshot, but this is definitely what I was thinking of).  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 8):

This reminds me of "Beneath the Planet of the Apes" where underground humans worshipped a doomsday device, the Alpha-Omega bomb.
[image: Alpha-Omega]